# post count is wrong when using same taxonomy for 2 different CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

1 custom taxonomy registered for 2 different CPT (custom post type). When i entered to edit tag section on edit-tags.php?taxonomy=mytaxonomy&post_type=cpt1 it displays total post count of 2 different CPT.  Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue see [Custom taxonomy count includes draft & trashed posts](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14084). It might not be fixed in version 3.2 but most likely in the next version.